# How to find x,a & b in $x^2-\frac{9}{16}=\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)$

Tags: polynomials

Find a & b such that $x^2-\frac{9}{16}=\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)$ for all real values of x.

How should this be started ? :)

Share your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to factor polynomials?

In general, an equation of the form $x^2-a^2$ can be factored as $(x-a)(x+a)$. Here, $a^2 = \frac{9}{16}$, so $a = \pm\frac{3}{4}$. So we have $x^2-\frac{9}{16} = (x-\frac{3}{4})(x+\frac{3}{4})$.

You could also use the quadratic formula and find roots, if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply out $(x-a)(x-b)$ and match the coefficients.

Multiplying out $(x-a)(x-b)$, we get:

$$
(x-a)(x-b) = x^2 -(a+b)x +ab
$$

Now this equals $x^2 - \frac{9}{16}$. So we can match the coefficients. Since $x^2 - \frac{9}{16}$ doesn't have a $x$ term, we need to remove the $x$ term in $x^2 -(a+b)x +ab$ by setting $a+b = 0$. Also, the constant term in $x^2 - \frac{9}{16}$ is $\frac{-9}{16}$ and thus $ab = \frac{-9}{16}$. You can solve from here.

$$
a = -b \\
$$
Substituting in, we get:
$$
-a^2 = \frac{-9}{16} \\ 
a = \pm\frac{3}{4}, \ b = \pm\frac{3}{4}
$$

Thus the solutions are $$a=\frac{3}{4}, b = \frac{-3}{4} \\ a=\frac{-3}{4}, b = \frac{3}{4}$$